# simulate a deterministic pushdown automaton (PDA) in c++

Tags: c++, finite-automata, pushdown-automaton

I was reading an exercise of UVA, which I need to simulate a deterministic pushdown automaton, to see
if certain strings are accepted or not by PDA on a given entry in the following format:

The first line of input will be an integer C, which indicates the number of test cases. The first line of each test case contains five integers E, T, F, S and C, where E represents the number of states in the automaton, T the number of transitions, F represents the number of final states, S the initial state and C the number of test strings respectively. The next line will contain F integers, which represent the final states of the automaton. Then come T lines, each with 2 integers I and J and 3 strings, L, T and A, where I and J (0 ≤ I, J < E) represent the state of origin and destination of a transition state respectively. L represents the character read from the tape into the transition, T represents the symbol found at the top of the stack and A the action to perform with the top of the stack at the end of this transition (the character used to represent the bottom of the pile is always Z. to represent the end of the string, or unstack the action of not taking into account the top of the stack for the transition character is used <alt+156> £). The alphabet of the stack will be capital letters. For chain A, the symbols are stacked from right to left (in the same way that the program JFlap, ie, the new top of the stack will be the character that is to the left). Then come C lines, each with an input string. The input strings may contain lowercase letters and numbers (not necessarily present in any transition).

The output in the first line of each test case must display the following string "Case G:", where G represents the number of test case (starting at 1). Then C lines on which to print the word "OK" if the automaton accepts the string or "Reject" otherwise.

For example:

```
Input:
2
3 5 1 0 5
2
0 0 1 Z XZ
0 0 1 X XX
0 1 0 X X
1 1 1 X £
1 2 £ Z Z
111101111
110111
011111
1010101
11011
4 6 1 0 5
3
1 2 b A £
0 0 a Z AZ
0 1 a A AAA
1 0 a A AA
2 3 £ Z Z
2 2 b A £
aabbb
aaaabbbbbb
c1bbb
abbb
aaaaaabbbbbbbbb
```

this is the output:

```
Output:
Case 1:
Accepted
Rejected
Rejected
Rejected
Accepted

Case 2:
Accepted
Accepted
Rejected
Rejected
Accepted
```

I need some help, or any idea how I can simulate this PDA, I am not asking me a code that solves the problem because I want to make my own code (The idea is to learn right??), But I need some help (Some idea or pseudocode) to begin implementation.

Comment: "automata" is the plural. "automaton" is the singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need a data structure to keep transitions. You can use a vector with a transition struct that contains transition quintuples. But you can use fact that states are integer and create a vector which keeps at index 0, transitions from state 0; at index 1 transitions from state 1 like that. This way you can reduce searching time for finding correct transition.

You can easily use the stack in stl library for the stack. You also need search function it could chnage depending on your implementation if you use first method you can use a function which is like:

```
int findIndex(vector<quintuple> v)//which finds the index of correct transition otherwise returns -1
```

then use the return value to get newstate and newstack symbol.

Or you can use a for loop over the vector and bool flag which represents transition is found or not.

On second method you can use a function which takes references to new state and new stack symbol and set them if you find a appropriate transition.

For inputs you can use something like vector or vector depends on personal taste. You can implement your main method with for loops but if you want extra difficulties you can implement a recursive function. May it be easy.

Comment: I'm using a vector with a transition struct that contains transition quintuples, I'm a little confused about what to create a search function.